# How to syntax highlight nested text with Prism in this language?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax-highlighting

I have a [CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/a-simple-share-url-forked-2r35t4?file=%2Findex.js%3A11%2C39), which shows this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { PrismLight as Code } from "react-syntax-highlighter";

// Code.registerLanguage('xml', xml)

note.displayName = "note";

/** @type {import('../core.js').Syntax} */
function note(Prism) {
  // https://www.json.org/json-en.html
  Prism.languages.note = {
    comment: {
      pattern: /# .*\n?/,
      greedy: true,
    },
    bracketed_term: {
      pattern: /{{([a-z][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*)}}/,
      greedy: true,
      alias: "string",
      inside: {
        term: {
          pattern: /([a-z][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*)/,
          greedy: true,
          alias: "tag",
        },
      },
    },
    nested_term: {
      pattern: /([a-z][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*)[ (]/,
      greedy: true,
      alias: "tag",
    },
    term: {
      pattern: /([a-z\.\/\*@][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*)/,
      greedy: true,
      alias: "keyword",
    },
    string: {
      pattern: /(<[^<>]+>)/,
      greedy: true,
      alias: "string",
    },
    bracket: {
      pattern: /[{}]/,
      greedy: true,
      alias: "string",
    },
    code: {
      pattern: /#\w\w+/,
      greedy: true,
      alias: "number",
    },
    number: {
      pattern: /-?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b/i,
      greedy: true,
    },
    punctuation: /[{}[\],]/,
    boolean: /\b(?:false|true)\b/,
  };
}

Code.registerLanguage("note", note);

const light = {
  'code[class*="language-"]': {
    color: "#333",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    background: "none",
    fontFamily: "Noto Sans Mono",
    textAlign: "left",
    whiteSpace: "pre",
    wordSpacing: "normal",
    wordBreak: "normal",
    wordWrap: "normal",
    lineHeight: "1.7",
    MozTabSize: "2",
    OTabSize: "2",
    tabSize: "2",
    WebkitHyphens: "none",
    MozHyphens: "none",
    msHyphens: "none",
    hyphens: "none",
  },
  'pre[class*="language-"]': {
    color: "#333",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontFamily: "Noto Sans Mono",
    textAlign: "left",
    whiteSpace: "pre",
    wordSpacing: "normal",
    wordBreak: "normal",
    wordWrap: "normal",
    lineHeight: "1.7",
    MozTabSize: "2",
    OTabSize: "2",
    tabSize: "2",
    WebkitHyphens: "none",
    MozHyphens: "none",
    msHyphens: "none",
    hyphens: "none",
    overflow: "auto",
  },
  ':not(pre) > code[class*="language-"]': {
    background: "#282a36",
    whiteSpace: "normal",
  },
  comment: {
    color: "#ccc",
    fontWeight: "normal",
  },
  prolog: {
    color: "#6272a4",
  },
  doctype: {
    color: "#6272a4",
  },
  cdata: {
    color: "#6272a4",
  },
  punctuation: {
    color: "#aaa",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  ".namespace": {
    Opacity: ".7",
  },
  property: {
    color: "#333",
  },
  tag: {
    color: "#333",
  },
  constant: {
    color: "#9248fc",
  },
  symbol: {
    color: "#9248fc",
  },
  deleted: {
    color: "#9248fc",
  },
  boolean: {
    color: "#3b82f6",
  },
  number: {
    color: "#34D399",
  },
  selector: {
    color: "#9248fc",
  },
  "attr-name": {
    color: "#aaa",
  },
  string: {
    color: "#9248fc",
  },
  char: {
    color: "#9248fc",
  },
  builtin: {
    color: "#9248fc",
  },
  inserted: {
    color: "#9248fc",
  },
  operator: {
    color: "#bbb",
  },
  entity: {
    color: "#333",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    cursor: "help",
  },
  url: {
    color: "#333",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  ".language-css .token.string": {
    color: "#333",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  ".style .token.string": {
    color: "#333",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  variable: {
    color: "#aaa",
  },
  atrule: {
    color: "#aaa",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  "attr-value": {
    color: "#9248fc",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  function: {
    color: "#111",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  "class-name": {
    color: "#111",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  keyword: {
    color: "#999",
  },
  regex: {
    color: "#34D399",
  },
  important: {
    color: "#34D399",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  bold: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
  italic: {
    fontStyle: "italic",
  },
};

const note3 = `deck @termsurf/base
  mark <0.0.1>
  head <A NoteText Package Manager>
  term link-text
  term computation
  term philosophy
  term information
  term platform
  term white-label
  term compiler
  face <Lance Pollard>, site <foo@bar.com>
  task ./task
  read ./note
  lock apache-2
  example <The moon's period is {bold(<28 days>)}
  link @termsurf/bolt, mark <0.x.x>
  link @termsurf/nest, mark <0.x.x>
  link @termsurf/crow, mark <0.x.x>`;

ReactDOM.render(
  <Code
    customStyle={{
      height: "100%",
      padding: 16,
      margin: 0,
    }}
    language="note"
    style={light}
  >
    {note3}
  </Code>,
  document.getElementById("base")
);
```

If you'll see the preview, notice the "example" line:

[image]

How do I make it so the text is highlighted properly, so it handles "terms" nested inside strings, nested inside terms, etc., recursively? More like this:

[image]

How can I change the definition of the syntax highlighter above to allow nested strings within terms? Terms are as defined in the highlighter, and they can be nested with parens, like `term-a(term-b, term-c(term-d, etc))`. But you can have strings within terms, and terms within strings.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up restructuring like this:

```
function note(Prism) {
  Prism.languages.note = {
    comment: {
      pattern: /# .*\n?/,
      greedy: true,
    },
    nested_term: {
      pattern: /([a-z][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*)\(.+\)/,
      inside: {
        paren: {
          pattern: /[\(\)]/,
          alias: 'punctuation',
        },
        line_string: {
          pattern: /<.+>/,
          inside: {
            angle_bracket: {
              pattern: /[<>]/,
              alias: 'string',
            },
            bracketed_term: {
              pattern: /{+.+}+/,
              inside: {
                curly_bracket: {
                  pattern: /[{}]/,
                  alias: 'nested_string',
                },
                nested_term: undefined,
                term: {
                  pattern:
                    /([a-z][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*)/,
                  alias: 'tag',
                },
              },
            },
            content: {
              pattern: /.+/,
              alias: 'string',
            },
          },
        },
        term: {
          pattern: /([a-z][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*)/,
          alias: 'tag',
        },
      },
    },
    line_string_start: {
      pattern: /<[^{>]*/,
      alias: 'string',
    },
    indented_term: {
      pattern: /([a-z][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*) /,
      inside: {
        term: {
          pattern: /([a-z][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*)/,
          alias: 'tag',
        },
        paren: {
          pattern: /\(/,
          alias: 'punctuation',
        },
      },
    },
    path: {
      pattern: /[@\.:\/\*][@\.:\/\-\+\?&\*a-zA-Z0-9]*/,
      alias: 'string',
    },
    term: {
      pattern: /([a-z][a-z0-9\/\.@\*]*(?:-+[a-z0-9\/\.@\*]+)*-*)/,
      alias: 'keyword',
    },
    line_string_end: {
      pattern: /}?[^{]*>/,
      alias: 'string',
    },
    code: {
      pattern: /#\w\w+/,
      greedy: true,
      alias: 'number',
    },
    number: {
      pattern: /-?\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?\b/i,
      greedy: true,
    },
    punctuation: /[\[\],]/,
    curly_bracket: {
      pattern: /[{}]/,
      greedy: true,
      alias: 'string',
    },
    // boolean: /\b(?:false|true)\b/,
  }

  Prism.languages.note.nested_term.inside.line_string.inside.bracketed_term.inside.nested_term =
    Prism.languages.note.nested_term
}
```

Notice the last line allows for some recursion it seems, but not too much.